# How to quick refactor to newer Ruby syntax using Vim script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, vim

I would like to quick refactor current line ex:

```
Subscription.create(:user => @user, :app => this_app, :verified => true, :approved => true)
```

to

```
Subscription.create(user: @user,app: this_app, verified: true, approved: true)
```

I would like to change that syntax only in line below cursor or in selected code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
:%s/:\([^ ]*\)\(\s*\)=>/\1:/g
```

stolen from [that blogpost](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/17450269990/convert-ruby-1-8-to-1-9-hash-syntax)

Note that you can also use [that gem](https://github.com/michaeledgar/hash_syntax/)

Comment: Hmm, But I would like to change that syntax only in line below cursor or in selected code.

Comment: if you want to change only for selection the command is `:'<,'>s/:\([^ ]*\)\(\s*\)=>/\1:/g`, but as the `'<,'>` are automatically added by vi when typing a command a while selecting code, you just have to add the `s/:\([^ ]*\)\(\s*\)=>/\1:/g` part

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i wanted :)